# Invertible sheaf on a scheme is coherent

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

If we define invertible sheaf as a locally free sheaf of rank 1, which is the most common definition. I saw it is true that an invertible sheaf must be quasi-coherent. But why is it also coherent?

**Update:** My concerns are related to the fact that $\mathcal{O}_X$, the structure sheaf, can be NOT coherent if it is not locally-Noetherian. See [Is locally free sheaf of finite rank coherent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164878/is-locally-free-sheaf-of-finite-rank-coherent) please.

Comment: [This is the quasi-coherent case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920320/quasi-coherent-sheaves-supset-locally-free-sheaves) using the cokernel definition of quasi-coherent sheaves. The same can be done for coherent sheaves by making the indices finite. See Hartshorne exercise II.5.4 for the equivalent definitions.

Comment: You're completely correct that there can be a non-coherent line bundle on a scheme. For instance, I give an example of a scheme where $\mathcal{O}_X$ is non-coherent [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3333153/). There's also a bit of discussion about comparing/contrasting coherent and locally finitely presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3973017/) which I think might help you with your issues. Briefly, in the locally noetherian world, coherent and locally of finite presentation are equivalent and folks often say the former when they really only need the latter.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you so much for sharing those useful links. In my question, I'm boldly guessing that there may exists an example of a non-locally Noetherian scheme where some invertible sheaf is not coherent? I guess that's why in some definition of invertible sheaf, they assume it is coherent. But I can't find one.(maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_X$ is an invertible sheaf, so I've already given you an example above.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "If we define invertible sheaf as a locally free sheaf of rank 1, which is the most common definition. I saw it is true that an invertible sheaf must be quasi-coherent. But why is it also coherent?"

**Answer:** The definition says that a sheaf $E \in Qcoh(X)$ on $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is coherent iff there is an affine open cover $U_i:=Spec(A_i)$ such that the restriction $E_{U_i}$ of $E$ to $U_i$ is isomorphic to $\tilde{E}_i$ where $E_i$ is a finitely generated $A_i$-module. If $L$ is an invertible sheaf, there is an open affine cover $U_i$ with $L_{U_i}\cong \tilde{A}_i$ and $A_i$ is a finitely generated $A_i$-module.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @hm2020. Your definition of coherent is equivalent to the original definition if $X$ scheme is locally Noetherian. What if it is not locally Noetherian? See my update, please.